# Assumptions related to PainPoints?

Tags: ux-field, best-practice

I am starting a simple service that helps with rent paperwork management. In this first phase of understanding the users, I bring the pertinent questions I should ask myself but also for the user.

I am "assuming" lot of things, but I have a difficult time knowing the difference between assumptions and the sense or the way we write them.

If I say: *"people don't like carrying a lot of documents with them"* or *"Homeowners have a lot problem setting appointments for visits"*.
Are these "assumptions"? are assumptions written on this way? We write assumptions related to our solution or product and never as a "pain point"? (or what I think users would say as I myself was in this situation).

Other (I think) assumptions might be:

- Gathering referrals
- Printing Referrals
- Thinking "nothing is missing"
- Not finding the desirable information in the advertisement (tenants)
- Answering always the same questions (homeowners)

That's what I thought it would my assumptions be. Is this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are all assumptions.

In Steve Krug's book "Don't Make me Think" a big point he talks about is that people often have the wrong idea with what they think their users will like/dislike. It really isn't until you start to do research that you get an idea for what actually bothers them. One big point, is that we assume if it bothers us, then it must be an annoyance to everyone else as well, which is not always the case.

It is only a pain point if you can show users dislike/have difficulty with it. If you can show that users have these difficulties with similar services it will make your points a lot more valid. If you don't have clients yet you can try to send out surveys or conduct interviews with people working with other companies or renting out their property alone. Find out what they think is frustrating about their process.

Another alternative is to present it objectively, "People renting out a property have to keep a lot of paper work with them.","Homeowners renting out a property have to find potential tenants and schedule appointments on their own, which can be time-consuming." Then you can provide how your company offers solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JivinJawanda !!